# ExpressJS Sessions and AWS Elastic Load Balancer Stickiness

Tags: node.js, session, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I want session affinity on my expressjs hosts that sit behind an AWS Elastic Load Balancer.

To do this do I put the 'connect.sid' cookie as the parameter if I "Enable Application Generated Cookie Stickiness" when enabling stickiness?

This assumes of course that I don't change the default cookie name in express.

Do I have to worry about the ELB clobbering my cookie?

Thanks

Comment: Was this working in your project? Can't get setup cookies/sesion handling behind a loadbalancer on aws.

Comment: Until I have time to actually test I just made my node box multi-core and used node clustering instead.

I don't think you need to set the application cookie in the AWS config - use the load balancer cookie option.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already switched and used the AWS cookie. Just had a wrong configuration for my session storage which was the initial problem. Now it's working.